# Write numpy's polyval() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, polynomials

I am trying to write a function that can replicate the numpy function, [np.polyval()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyval.html)

here is my current code:

```
def eval(poly, x):
    result = 0  
    for i in poly:
      y = (x ** (len(poly) - poly.index(i)-1))
      result += y
  return result
```

`poly` is supposed be a list formatted for the [numpy.poly1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) function

but the problem with this code, is when `x` is equal to a negative number

can someone help me with this code?

Comment: note that your function name overwrites the built-in [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found this snippet of code to work similar to np.polyval() function:

```
def poly(polynomial: list,value: int):
    final = 0
    for i in range(len(polynomial)):
        final += (value**i)*polynomial[(-1*i)-1]
    return final
```

Explanation using an example: `poly([1,-5,5],-3)`

`range(len(polynomial))` returns 0,1,2 per iteration. those are also the powers we need for the quadratic equation. The `(value**i)*polynomial[(-1*i)-1]` expression takes our value (in this case -3) and gives it the value of i (i.e (-3)^0,(-3)^1,(-3)^2). and then multiplies it with `polynomial[(-1*i)-1]`th index of the list provided. (-1 when i=0;-2 when i=1 and -3 when i=2).

Finally it adds all of this together and returns a value.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!  Do you know how I can find these snippets?  They seem very useful to understand how the functions work

Comment: Oh, I just made that. Just basic logic I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `math.pow` function ?

```
import math
def func(poly, x):
  result=0
  i=1
  for p in poly:
    result += p*math.pow(x, len(poly)-i)
    i+=1
  return result
```

This is from `numpy.polyval` page:

> If p is of length N, this function returns the value:
>
> ```
> p[0]*x**(N-1) + p[1]*x**(N-2) + ... + p[N-2]*x + p[N-1]
> ```

Comment: It doesn't work when poly = ```[-1, 0, 0, 1]``` and ```x = -1```